# what is the good practice of providing version info to end users in Web application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, version

I see that not all Web applications would provide version info to end users. If a Web application does, the version is displayed at the bottom of the home page, like Magento and Prestashop etc.

I am building an ASP.NET MVC application, and would provide version info. My first thought was that the assembly/file version of the entry assembly of the MVC project could be the application version, however, altering CSHTML, javascript, CSS, as well as upgrading 3rd party dependencies like jQuery and Bootstrap may result in features changes.

Are there some conventional or best practices to management version numbers to be presented somewhere in the Web application?

Comment: To clarify, I am not really asking how to display (store and show), but overall good practice, for example, in what scenarios, increment the version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is store the Version Number in the AppSettings of your Web Config and then Update That as part of either your build pipeline (TeamCity) or preferably your deployment server (Octopus Deploy). Then your cshtml can read that value and display to your users. That's the solution we adopted.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](https://semver.org/)

From the Summary:

Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:

1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner, and
3. PATCH version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.

Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.